# Using Google Application Default Credentials (ADC) with gcloud-aio Storage in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, aio

I'm using [gcloud-aio/storage](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/tree/master/storage) to access GCS buckets, with the authentication via service account key file (JSON file).  Here's my working Python code:

```
from os import path
from gcloud.aio.auth import Token
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only"]

pwd = path.realpath(path.dirname(__file__))
service_file = path.join(pwd, "../../my_key.json")
token = Token(service_file=service_file, scopes=SCOPES)
async with Storage(token=token) as storage:
    _ = await storage.list_objects(bucket_name)
```

I'd like to instead authenticate via Application Default Credentials, and typically use this code to get an access token:

```
from google.auth import default
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

credentials, project_id = default(scopes=SCOPES)
_ = Request()
credentials.refresh(_)
access_token = credentials.token
```

But can't figure out how (or if) I can pass this type of token to aio storage.